# undefined method `total_pages' for #<Recipe::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fb4045fec58>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know if someone sees the problem

I am using the gem will_paginate

**My Recipe model:**

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :ingredients, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reviews, dependent: :destroy

  self.per_page = 10
end
```

**My RecipesController:**

```
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!
  def index
    if params[:search]
      @recipes = Recipe.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).order("created_at DESC")
    else
      @recipes = Recipe.all.page(params[:page]).order('created_at DESC')
    end
  end

  def show
    @review = Review.new
    @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
    @user = User.find(@recipe.user_id)
    @full_name = @recipe.user.first_name + " " + @recipe.user.last_name
  end
end
```

**app/views/recipes/index.html.erb:**

```
<%= will_paginate @recipes %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the people who might care or have the same problem. I found the solution:

I changed ***self.per_page = 10*** to ***WillPaginate.per_page = 10*** inside the Recipe model.